# Order at GroupBy In NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am new in NHibernate, I can't handle this problem.

I have class like this

```
public class Ticket
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual string Number { get; set; }
  public virtual string Comment { get; set; }

  public virtual DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }

  public virtual bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

This class is related to table Tickets in database.
I want to get list of all years involved in Tickets by IssueDate field.

This is my query:

```
var years = session.Query<Ticket>()        
.GroupBy(a => a.IssueDate.Year)        
.ToList();
```

and I get all involved years in list 2017, 2014, 2016, 2012....
but I can't apply any Order command to this query! I need to output list look like 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically creating a List of grouping there rather than a list of years.

Try this instead:

```
var years = session.Query<Ticket>()        
    .Select(a => a.IssueDate.Year) // select Year component of the IssueDate
    .Distinct()                    // unique years only
    .OrderBy(year => year)         // order by year
    .ToList();
```

The key is to know what the return type is after each LINQ step, so that we know what we can do to that return type. Sometimes it helps to break up the LINQ into separate steps.

```
// years is IQueryable<int>
var years = session.Query<Ticket>()        
    .Select(a => a.IssueDate.Year); // select Year component of the IssueDate

// unique years only
var uniqueYears = years.Distinct();

// apply order then return List
var orderedYears = uniqueYears.OrderBy(year => year).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @steven, but I still can't  apply OrderBy command. Always getting error "System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'".